# Do I need to create a full app to use the Facebook SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm working on a custom wordpress plugin for my site. I have multiple accounts so I'll need multiple feeds. I'm using the Fascebook SDK v3 (My server has an older version of PHP that the newest SDK doesn't work on). I've downloaded and included the correct files, no errors.

I then logged into one of my accounts and created a new app to get the App ID and Secret Key. However, my plugin doesn't work because it says it's not "live".

I need to do a submit and review that requires icons, screenshots, etc. However, I don't want my app available to everyone just my page.

Comment: What is your plugin doing that requires access to the Facebook SDK?

Comment: All I need to get is the page's profile image, page url, and x number of recent posts. Of course I assume I need the SDK for this since I needed similar info for the twitter feed portion of the plugin.

Comment: _“I need to do a submit and review that requires icons, screenshots, etc.”_ – no, you don’t. You just need to set it “live” on the top of Status&Review tab in app dashboard, that’s all. (And as long as you don’t specifically set it up for any platform, other users won’t be able to “do” much with your app, even though it is now public.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a Facebook app for this. Apps are for situations where you need to access or modify information on other users' accounts. In situations like this one, where you only need to work with information which you personally have access to, the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) should be sufficient.

You will need to [create a page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) for the page in question, then access [endpoints related to the page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page) to get information on the page, or read its posts.

Comment: Looks like that works aside from the access token expires. Do you know how I can create an access token that doesn't expire?

Comment: From what I understand, as long as you go through the process to create a long-lived token, its lifetime will be extended automatically as long as you keep using it. Refer to the "Expiration and Extending Tokens" section of the access token documentation for details.

Comment: It looks like I need app info may be need to create that, from what I can tell. It says to take a short lived token and make a call using the short-lived token, app-id, and app-secret to `/oauth/access_token?`

Comment: Oh, right. For personal use I believe you can create a token using the Graph Explorer app? Not sure if you can make a long-lived token through that though. :/